# What % of asylum seekers who entered the EU during the 2015 European migrant crisis are now fluent in the local language?

Tags: european-union, languages, asylum

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_European_migrant_crisis):

> The 2015 European migrant crisis, also known internationally as the Syrian refugee crisis, was a period of significantly increased movement of refugees and migrants into Europe in 2015, when 1.3 million people came to the continent to request asylum, the most in a single year since World War II. Those requesting asylum in Europe in 2015 were mostly Syrians, but also included significant numbers of Afghans, Nigerians, Pakistanis, Iraqis and Eritreans, as well as economic migrants from the Balkans.

Now that it's been ~7 years since the crisis has started, do we have any data on what % of refugees have become fluent speakers of the local language? I'd define "fluent" as being capable of speaking the language at the C1 level of the  [CEFR guideline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages#Common_reference_levels).

Comment: Just for context, what proportion of first generation immigrants to the US in the 19th and 20th century achieved C1 proficiency during their life time?

Comment: @quarague that's an excellent question for History.SE!

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about politics, although I grant you could use the answer to prove a political point.

Comment: @StuartF It might be about politics. For example if that percentage varies between countries and if that is due to the offering or not of language courses for example. My guess (at least 50%) although fluent is a bit of a high bar. I would be satisfied with level A2-B1 which should be fine for many jobs for example.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit, one of the critical factors would be the age mix of the migrants. Seven years later, probably almost all children who migrated are fluent by now. Probably a very small share of elderly migrants, if there are any elderly migrants, are fluent. In between, it would be much less than 100% and significantly more than 0% but what percentage is hard to predict so we'd have to look at data. Age, interactions with the local population, and prior language instruction would all be factors. Virtually all adults, no matter how fluent, would have an easily discernible accent.

Comment: Linguistic integration - and government support to achieve it - are key elements to successful integration of immigrants, so claiming it has nothing to do with SE.Po's subject seems very, very odd.  That said, using the C1 level seems unduly demanding - *Can use language flexibly and effectively for social, **academic** and professional purposes./Can produce clear, **well-structured, detailed text** on complex subjects,* - seems to be a high bar for even natives of a country.  Not because they can't, because their day-to-day life and job does not require it.

Comment: Plus, Goethe's and Alliance's - who presumably can score grants to do so - claims that 700-1200 hours are sufficient to achieve C2 seems farfetched and self-interested.  As well as unrealistic with older immigrants who will have lost linguistic plasticity.  **A good Q, even if the answers may be uncomfortable, but the bar given is much too high.**

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica what % of people born in Germany to German parents won't pass the C1 language test?

Comment: Look at C1 definition.  Take the average 30 year German-born carpenter.  Is he going to be able, spontaneously, to write academic papers, when administered this test, as per this definition given?  If he decides to enroll in a university, he may very well struggle for a short while, then adapt and excel.  But he may not meet that threshold when given the test.  So your chosen metric seems simplistic, even if the Q is both on topic here and worth asking.

Comment: Seems to me this Q is getting VTCed as immigrant-bashing.  Thing is, to take an immigrant-friendly PoV, not taking care to integrate immigrants linguistically, and not even tracking any metrics, is not doing said immigrants any favors.  Not unlike, in a way, the refusal of many European countries to track ethnicity statistics which affects the capability of states to identify systematic discrimination by some employers, compared to the USA's [EEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_Employment_Opportunity_Commission) metrics.

Comment: @JonathanReez I am not going to be drawn into that debate.  Just answering the Q because it feels relevant from either a pro or anti refugee PoV.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I had 8 years of French from age 11 through 19.  I spent a summer in France when I was 15.  I've lived in Geneva for a year and a half, and the chance of my reaching C1 is pretty small.  I agree that the threshold is poorly chosen.  A2 or perhaps B1 seem more realistic for younger adults and A1 for older.  But indeed the fact that many native speakers cannot "produce clear, well-structured, detailed text on complex subjects, showing controlled use of organisational patterns, connectors and cohesive devices" shows that C1 is an unrealistic metric for assimilation.

Comment: "If the 39%...were deported...": That betrays a significantly oversimplified misapprehension of the dynamics underlying racism and xenophobia.  For example, economically challenged native Europeans are going to resent economically successful immigrants whether or not they're assimilated.  The question also ignores the fact that most targets of racism and xenophobia in western Europe have nothing to do with asylum or refugees but rather are the descendants of economic migrants who arrived (legally) in the decades following the second world war.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Between Integration and Return:
The Reality of New Syrian Refugees
in Europe
A Survey of Refugees in Germany,
France, the Netherlands, and Sweden](https://tda-sy.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Between-Integration-and-Return-29-01-2021.pdf) This, 2021, long, report gives some indication about specifically the Syrian refugees.  This seems self-reported, rather than test-assessed.

> The percentage of those defining their level of host-country language proficiency as “good” or “very good” was largest
> among those in the 18-25 age group. **According to the survey, 61.2% of respondents aged 18-25 said their language level
> is “good” or “very good,” while 43.6% of respondents aged 26-39 rated their language proficiency level as “good” or “very
> good.” Among those 40-55 years, this percentage dropped to 20%.** A clear difference can be seen between the average
> within the younger age group and the overall average of respondents who said their level of language proficiency is “good”
> or “very good,” which was about 37%.
>
> This apparent relation between age and language proficiency level is linked to several factors, including the faster learning
> process for younger people and the involvement of a large number of younger people, especially those 18-25 years, in the
> educational process that helps raise host-country language proficiency levels.

Seems like a clear could do better.  Either for the immigrants or the host country.  I found it by way of [Europe’s mounting challenge to integrate Syrian refugees @ TRTWorld](https://www.trtworld.com/magazine/europe-s-mounting-challenge-to-integrate-syrian-refugees-43929) which went on to say Sweden had the worst rate of the 4 countries, something I found surprising.

Overall, seems like a really in depth survey, also covering other subjects like social liberalism or employment rates.

Otherwise, this subject seems sparsely covered.  For example, I found a [Netherland report that refers to a survey](https://fra.europa.eu/en/promising-practices/survey-migrant-integration).  Said survey data is said to be unavailable to the general public, but links to summaries are provided.  Links which then 404 in English, and lead to long lists of not-all-relevant documents in Dutch.

p.s. adding a comment I made about the criteria cited in the Q:

> using the C1 level seems unduly demanding - *Can use language flexibly and effectively for social, academic and professional purposes./Can produce clear, well-structured, detailed text on complex subjects* - seems to be a high bar for even natives of a country. Not because they can't, because their day-to-day life and job does not require it.

Plus, from personal experience, 600 to 1200 hours of class time does not result in C2 - top level - proficiency in a language.  Not even close, so the effort required seems very underestimated.